# Can we set up implicit interfaces in Dart?

Tags: dart

Dart has an `interface` class modifier, which allows us to do things like (taken from [the dart.dev documentation](https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers)):

```dart
interface class Vehicle {
  void moveForward(int meters) {
    // ...
  }
}

class MockVehicle implements Vehicle {
  @override
  void moveForward(int meters) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Is it possible to define an *implicit* interface in Dart?

For example, let's say we have different classes, perhaps from different libraries, that have all defined a `length` property and the indexing operator. An interface might look something like:

```dart
abstract interface class Indexable {
  num operator [](int index);
  int get length;
}
```

Now we want to write a function that accepts any object that hase these defined. As a simple example:

```dart
num sum(Indexable xs) {
  var total = 0.0;
  for (var i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
    total += xs[i];
  }
  return total;
}
```

However, for example, even though `List<num>` supports the above operations, it does not *explicitly* implement `Indexable` as defined above, so the following doesn't work.

```dart
void main() {
  final xs = [3, 4, 2, 5];
  print(sum(xs));
}
```

Is it possible to set up interfaces such that objects that do not necessarily *explicitly* implement interfaces (but implicitly do) can be passed to functions expecting the interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible directly. If you want to stay typesafe and avoid `dynamic`, you can write a wrapper that handles it:

```
abstract interface class Indexable {
  num operator [](int index);
  int get length;
}

num sum(Indexable xs) {
  var total = 0.0;
  for (var i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
    total += xs[i];
  }
  return total;
}

class IndexableWrapperImplementation<T> implements Indexable
{
  final int Function(T) getLength;
  final num Function(T, int index) getItem;
  final T instance;
  
  IndexableWrapperImplementation(this.instance, this.getLength, this.getItem);
  
  @override
  num operator [](int index){
    return getItem(instance, index);
  }
  
  @override
  int get length => getLength(instance);
}


void main() {
  final intList = [3, 4, 2, 5];
  final wrapper = IndexableWrapperImplementation(intList, (x) => x.length, (x, index) => x[index]);
  print(sum(wrapper));
}
```

Comment: Neat workaround. I struggle to see how the keyword `interface` adds much to the language; your code works the same with simply an `abstract class`. I'd have expected `interface` to imply that we are defining a set of requirements for the argument rather than the argument class explicitly implements the interface... In any case, thanks for the response!

Comment: @RichardAmbler The keyword `interface` only means that this class can only be "implemented" and not "extended" by another class.

It's not something like `trait`s from Rust.

See: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1612

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. However you can "duck-type" using `dynamic` even though it's somewhat inefficient.

```dart
num sum(dynamic xs) {
  var total = 0.0;
  for (var i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
    total += xs[i];
  }
  return total;
}

void main() {
  final xs = [3, 4, 2, 5];
  print(sum(xs)); // Works!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Using a dynamic type means coding blind, however, and I'm specifically trying to get the benefits of interfacing.